# Susy Grid not getting Grid Padding

Tags: css, grid, sass, susy-compass

I am trying to add another grid inside my main grid on an element of `.fat`. My code is:

```
footer
  .fat
    $container-width: 100%
    +with-grid-settings($columns: 8, $padding: 10px)
      +susy-grid-background
```

It's all working however, there is no 10px of padding on the left and right of the grid.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you'll have to add the actual padding yourself. Since grid backgrounds are fluid (`%`-based) and grid-padding can use any units, the grid-padding is not factored into the background image. Instead, we use `background-origin` and `background-clip` to confine the image inside the `content` box.

Also, in this case, since you are not actually setting the width anywhere, you don't need a `$container-width` setting. Here's what you need:

```
footer
  .fat
    +with-grid-settings($columns: 8, $padding: 10px)
      +susy-grid-background
      padding: 0 $grid-padding
```

Comment: It does work fine but a few questions about why it works if that's ok?

- You say I don't need the `$container-width` var, on older version of Susy I didn't need it but when I updated, it tried to keep my columns the same size as the main grid rather then sorting the column widths out itself. On the new version, I have to add that variable so the column widths fit the available space.

- Why do I need to set `$padding: 10px` inside the mixin arguments when I am setting it further on after the grid background?

Comment: I don't understand the questions, but I'll try and explain. In the sample you showed, you set a $container-width variable, but it isn't being used by any of the other code in your sample - so you can remove it. Only the `container` mixin uses that setting, so unless you use that mixin, the setting is pointless. With grid-padding, you are also changing the setting, but only applying it to the background image - not to the actual element. You need it both places, and it doesn't matter which order you apply those.